# Using libXL with PHP and mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I'm working on importing and exporting very high volumes of data from Excel into/out of MySQL via PHP. I have a working solution but it is very memory intensive and slow.

I have seen that a developer has produced a Unix build PHP script incorporating libXL - a very fast C library for excel that costs about $200. This purports to process 10,000 cells in 0.03 secs using 262kb of PHP memory.

I also notice that someone posting on this site is developing a stand alone dll based on libXL which I don't think will be suitable for my purpose.

Questions:

Is anyone out there looking to produce a simple to implement PHP libaray built around libXL which I could deploy on both a local Windows based XAMPP rig and onto my UNIX based host (Hostpapa while I'm developing)

Would I need to buy libXL for both Windows and UNIX to work both locally and on-line

Are there any other PHP solutions which are very fast and have low memory requirements

I have tried every PHP solution suggested by the PHPExcel developer, Mark Baker (thanks Mark), and nothing meets my requirements fully so no suggestions along those lines please.

I am considering learning Perl so I can use the excellent Excel parser that exists but unfortunately I've got time constraints and I think that will take me too long.

Answer (score 1):

I am using libXL for my requirements, which involve parsing large amounts of cells in linux, its well worth the money, and in my opinion none of other PHP Excel solutions can match this coz it is a compiled solution. You can find more info here:
http://www.king-foo.be/2011/05/a-first-attempt-at-the-php-excel-extension/